# Saving metabox repeatable fields

Tags: php, plugin-development, metabox

This is a code that I'm adapting from https://gist.github.com/2057532. The problem is that I'm not being able to save the content from the new fields that I created. I had checked the other questions here, but none helped me. Any idea where is the problem?

```
add_action('admin_init', 'slider_metabox_caption', 1);
function slider_metabox_caption() {
add_meta_box( 'repeatable-fields', 'Captions', 'repeatable_metabox_display', 'slide', 'normal', 'high'); }

function repeatable_metabox_display() {
global $post;

$repeatable_fields = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'repeatable_fields', true);
wp_nonce_field( 'repeatable_meta_box_nonce', 'repeatable_meta_box_nonce' ); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.metabox_submit').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#publish').click();
        });
        $('#add-row').on('click', function() {
            var row = $('.empty-row.screen-reader-text').clone(true);
            row.removeClass('empty-row screen-reader-text');
            row.insertBefore('#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last');
            return false;
        });
        $('.remove-row').on('click', function() {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            return false;
        });

        $('#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody').sortable({
            opacity: 0.6,
            revert: true,
            cursor: 'move',
            handle: '.sort'
        });
    });
</script>

<table id="repeatable-fieldset-one" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="1%"></th>
            <th width="15%">Text</th>
            <th width="4%">Fx</th>
            <th width="4%">Easing</th>
            <th width="4%">Speed</th>
            <th width="4%">X</th>
            <th width="4%">Y</th>
            <th width="4%">Width</th>
            <th width="4%">Height</th>
            <th width="1%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <?php 
    if ( $repeatable_fields ) :
        foreach ( $repeatable_fields as $field ) { ?>

    <tr>
        <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">-</a></td>

        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="text[]" value="<?php if($field['text'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['text'] ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="fx[]" value="<?php if($field['fx'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['fx'] ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="easing[]" value="<?php if($field['easing'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['easing'] ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="speed[]" value="<?php if($field['speed'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['speed'] ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="x[]" value="<?php if($field['x'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['x'] ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="y[]" value="<?php if($field['y'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['y'] ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="width[]" value="<?php if($field['width'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['width'] ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="height[]" value="<?php if($field['height'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['height'] ); ?>" /></td>

        <td><a class="sort">|||</a></td>

    </tr>
    <?php } else : 
    // show a blank one ?>

    <tr>
        <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">-</a></td>

        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="text[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="fx[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="easing[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="speed[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="x[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="y[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="width[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="height[]" /></td>

        <td><a class="sort">|||</a></td>

    </tr>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- empty hidden one for jQuery -->
    <tr class="empty-row screen-reader-text">
        <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">-</a></td>

        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="text[]" /></td>        
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="fx[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="easing[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="speed[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="x[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="y[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="width[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="height[]" /></td>

        <td><a class="sort">|||</a></td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add another</a>
<input type="submit" class="metabox_submit" value="Save" />
</p>

<?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'repeatable_meta_box_save');
function repeatable_meta_box_save($post_id) {
if ( ! isset( $_POST['repeatable_meta_box_nonce'] ) ||
    ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['repeatable_meta_box_nonce'], 'repeatable_meta_box_nonce' ) )
    return;

if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
    return;

if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
    return;

$old = get_post_meta($post_id, 'repeatable_fields', true);
$new = array();

$text = $_POST['text'];
$fx = $_POST['fx'];
$easing = $_POST['easing'];
$speed = $_POST['speed'];
$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];
$width = $_POST['width'];
$height = $_POST['height'];

$count = count( $text );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
    if ( $text[$i] != '' ) :
        $new[$i]['text'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $text[$i] ) );

    elseif ( $fx[$i] != '' ) :
        $new[$i]['fx'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $fx[$i] ) );

    elseif ( $easing[$i] != '' ) :
        $new[$i]['easing'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $easing[$i] ) );

    elseif ( $speed[$i] != '' ) :
        $new[$i]['speed'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $speed[$i] ) );

    elseif ( $x[$i] != '' ) :
        $new[$i]['x'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $x[$i] ) );

    elseif ( $y[$i] != '' ) :
        $new[$i]['y'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $y[$i] ) );

    elseif ( $width[$i] != '' ) :
        $new[$i]['width'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $width[$i] ) );

    elseif ( $height[$i] != '' ) :
        $new[$i]['height'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $height[$i] ) );

    endif;
}

if ( !empty( $new ) && $new != $old )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'repeatable_fields[$i]', $new );
elseif ( empty($new) && $old )
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'repeatable_fields[$i]', $old );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following code allows you to retrieve the array.

```
foreach ($repeatable_fields as $v) {

}
```

Than you can access individual values with something like this:

```
<?php echo $v['text']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be that you are saving it wrong, change this:

```
if ( !empty( $new ) && $new != $old )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'repeatable_fields[$i]', $new );
elseif ( empty($new) && $old )
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'repeatable_fields[$i]', $old );
```

to this:

```
if ( !empty( $new ) && $new != $old )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'repeatable_fields', $new );
elseif ( empty($new) && $old )
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'repeatable_fields', $old );
```

Comment: Yeah.. however now it's giving me Notice: Undefined index:

Comment: The code works almost fine now. One last thing: Do the repeatable fields get serialized in the database? If yes, how can I retrieve the data?

Comment: yes its stored as a serialized array and you get it using `$repeatable_fields = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'repeatable_fields', true);`

Comment: Thanks. But don't I need to unserialize the array? Because when I use the code you provided, I just get the word 'Array' printed.

Comment: @Daniel You now use `$repeatable_fields` in a `foreach` statement such as `foreach ($repeatable_fields as $field) { echo $field; }` as an example.